# 403 forbidden error; checked everything I can

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-403, httpforbiddenhandler

I'm getting a 403 forbidden error on every part of my wordpress website. I can't even get to wp-admin.
On top of that I get this error: "Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

What I already checked:

- user server login settings
- permissions
- DNS IP address
- htaccess file
- updating wordpress

htaccess file looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I'm out of solutions and can't find any other ones on the interwebs. Does anyone here have some experience with the same problem or any solutions?

Much thanks in advance!

Comment: I would suggest deactivating your plugins, and reactivating them one at a time, to see if one of them is causing some sort of conflict. Or try just deactivating any you've recently updated first, to see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: maybe something like the user running apache as no access to the folder on the server?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I deactivated all plugins at first by renaming the folder, it didn't work. Maybe renaming is not enough? What else is a method for deactivating plugins in terminal?

Comment: The only things apache controls are .htaccess and my media folder, the rest is owned by the user. Do any of those two have to be owned by the user as well?